# ω1 disconnected

Tags: general-topology

What is the reason that $ω1 (ω1 + 1)$ is disconnected?

My idea is that we know every uncountable well order set contains a copy of ω + 1 as an initial segment. So for ω1 (ω1 + 1), we can find the smallest element after ω, and call it ω + 1, and proceeds to find ω + 2, ω +3, etc.

So $\{ω + 1, ω +2\}$, on one hand equals (ω , ω +3), which is clearly open. While on the other hand, complement of {ω + 1, ω +2} is $(ω + 2, \infty)$ union  $(-\infty, ω + 1)$, so $\{ω + 1, ω +2\}$ is also closed. And this tell us that we have some non trivial clopen sets, and thus ω1 (ω1 + 1) is not connected.

Is the above argument correct? Are there some better ways to show the disconnectedness of ω1 (ω1 + 1)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your argument is fine, but it is more natural to start from the beginning of $\omega_1$, not at $\omega$ itself.

You also only need to show that $\omega_1$ has a singleton $\{p\}$ that is open (since the complement $(-\infty, p) \cup (p, +\infty)$ is open). The most natural $p$ to pick is the minimal element of $\omega_1$.